# Java KeyEvent - Key Code vs Extended Key Code

Tags: java, keyevent, keycode

I noticed the Java KeyEvent object has a getExtendedKeyCode() method and a getKeyCode() method, which both return integers. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) indicates that while getKeyCode() should be used for US-specific keyboards, getExtendesKeyCode() can be used for international keyboards that support more than just Unicode characters. For example, you would potentially want/need to use getExtendedKeyCode() for a Thai-language application.

In other words, getKeyCode() will pick up on all Unicode characters, while getExtendedKeyCode() will detect a wider range of characters.

You can read about the difference between Unicode-compliant and non-Unicode-compliant languages [here](https://irfansworld.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/what-is-unicode-and-non-unicode-data-formats/)

Comment: Is there any real reason to not always use extended keycodes? Don't they support all US keys too?